# Filter posts by meta key

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

I would like to implement a search function where a user can enter an amount($amount) and based on that argument the search result needs to show all posts where $amount >= loan_min (meta key) AND $amount <= loan_max (meta key)

Let's suppose we have a post that has meta keys loan_min=100 and loan_max=500 then say entering 200 in search will show this post but if a user enters 50 or 550 in search then this post will not be showing in the result.

Here is how it is coded.

```
$meta_query =   array(  
                                    
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                        array( 
                                                 
                                                'key'      => 'minimum_loan_amount',
                                                'value'    =>  $loan_amount_requested,
                                                'type'     => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'  => '>='
                             
                                            ),
                                            array( 
                                                 
                                                'key'      => 'maximum_loan_amount',
                                                'value'    =>  $loan_amount_requested,
                                                'type'     => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'  => '<='
                             
                                            )
                                                    
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing the meta key parameters. you can filter you posts.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'post_type',(optional)
'meta_key'   => 'age',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'loan_min',
        'value'   => $amount,
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'loan_min',
        'value'   => $amount,
        'compare' => '<=',
    ),
),
```

);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

You can try with this code.
For more query you can visit this site: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: I already tried this but for some reason, it's not working, Although a single meta key is working, using both meta keys with AND is not working.  I updated the question with the code I'm usnig.